# find the length of a string without using loops, built in methods, or .length property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion, string-length

I have been stuck on this problem for quite sometime. In addition to not using built in methods and the length property, we cannot use any loops either, which is a giveaway that this problem must be solved with recursion. I have tried this function but I am still stuck.

```
function getLength(string, length = 0){
  if (string[0] === undefined) {return length};
  length++;

  return getLength(length);
}

console.log(getLength("hello")) 
// expected answer: 5
```

Comment: Think about what your passing into your function here: `return getLength(length)`. Notice anything missing that it might need?

Comment: thank you, when I pass in the string as well the call stack overflows

Comment: That's just a tip to get you going in the right direction. The other thing is that your passing the same string always, so `string[0]` is always going to give the same value. As the answer already has you would want to do `string[length]` instead. As that's checking the position of the string incrementally until it hits the end. Then the `length` returned will be the length of the string itself when it hits a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

You’re very close.

```
function getLength(string, length = 0){
  if (string[length] === undefined) {return length};
  length++;

  return getLength(string, length);
}

console.log(getLength("hello")) 
// expected answer: 5
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I could have sworn I tried this solution, but obviously not!

Answer (score 0):

You already figured the answer you just missed few parameters

```js
function getLength(string, length = 0) {
  if (string[length] === undefined) {
    return length
  };
  length++;

  return getLength(string, length);
}

console.log(getLength("hello"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the *base case* of the recursion which would terminate the recursion, as when either the string which is passed is *empty*/`undefined`/`null` or the the index at which you are in the recursive process has exceed the length of the given string in which case you would return `0`.

Then call the function recursively by incrementing the index of the string and adding `1` in each recursive process till you hit the base condition:

```js
function getLength(str, idx = 0) {
  //base case
  if (!str || !str[idx]) {
    return 0;
  }
  return 1 + getLength(str, idx + 1);
}
console.log(getLength("hello"));
```